Content Hub Webhook Action not Working with Connect
Trying to do a webmethod call to Connect from Content Hub in an Action. Call works fine from Postman, but doesn't work from Content Hub. Content Hub says it does, but Connect never gets the call. Any step I might be missing?


In order for the Webhook to get triggered inside Sitecore Connect from Content Hub, you will first need to attach the Action to Trigger inside Content Hub, so that the Webhook gets initialized with the request payload whenever the event from Content Hub is received.
You can attach Action to Trigger inside Content Hub by navigating to Actions tab as below.

Thereafter when the Trigger executes the Action attached on the Content Hub, Webhook receives that event with the request payload as below.

Using above way, you can successfully connect to Webhook from Sitecore Content Hub.
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks @ckhanna that got me in the correct place to look. I had to modify my condition in the trigger and it worked.

Glad to hear that @RReilley!!!
